# Actionscript3, Starling and Box2D resources and tutorials

Tags: apache-flex, box2d, starling-framework

I am looking for some tutorials and resources on getting started with starling framework for actionscript3 and box2d. Unfortunately I could not find so many samples with source code where i could see some real action behaviour.

Could someone of you share some resources, or links to tutorials / apps you have developed so far using this technologies. That would be of a great help for fellow developers :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Introducing Starling, from O'Reilly (which can be downloaded for free) is a good start (not too different from the manual that can be downloaded from the Starling site)

Comment: Thanks, looks nice! I see there is a chapter named "Plugging Starling with Box2D", that may help. Anyway.. some live samples would be nice too :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a great tutorial over on [www.hsharma.com](http://www.hsharma.com/tutorials/starting-with-starling-ep-1-intro-setup/) that comes with all the project files so you can try it out for yourself. Unfortunately, it's only about Starling, but it gives you a solid base to start from.

Comment: Yep.. indeed I follow him on twitter and also his blog. Really nice tutorials from his side. +1 from my side for your post!